# Apache Flink got exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to work with offloaded serialized shuffle descriptors

Tags: java, scala, apache-flink

I am using Flink on the cluster. As I submitted the task, I got the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to work with offloaded serialized shuffle descriptors.
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeRelay(CompletableFuture.java:326)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeRelay(CompletableFuture.java:338)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniRelay(CompletableFuture.java:925)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniRelay.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:913)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1990)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaInvocationHandler.lambda$invokeRpc$0(AkkaInvocationHandler.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:774)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:750)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1990)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$1.onComplete(FutureUtils.java:1079)
        at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:263)
        at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:261)
        at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:191)
        at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:188)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.Executors$DirectExecutionContext.execute(Executors.java:73)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:44)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:252)
        at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:572)
        at akka.remote.DefaultMessageDispatcher.dispatch(Endpoint.scala:101)
        at akka.remote.EndpointReader$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(Endpoint.scala:999)
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
        at akka.remote.EndpointActor.aroundReceive(Endpoint.scala:458)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java. lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to work with offloaded serialized shuffle descriptors.
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.deployment.InputGateDeploymentDescriptor.getShuffleDescriptors(InputGateDeploymentDescriptor.java:150)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.partition.consumer.SingleInputGateFactory.create(SingleInputGateFactory.java:125)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.NettyShuffleEnvironment.createInputGates(NettyShuffleEnvironment.java:261)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.<init>(Task.java:420)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor.submitTask(TaskExecutor.java:737)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor32.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.lambda$handleRpcInvocation$1(AkkaRpcActor.java:316)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:83)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:314)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:217)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:163)
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:24)
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:20)
        at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
        at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:122)
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:20)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537)
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:535)
        at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:220)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:580)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:548)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:175)
```

Flink version: 1.13.6;
Scala version: 2.11
Kafka version: 2.2.2

Part of my code:

```
object batchProcess {
  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {
    val host = "localhost"
    val port = 6379
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    // read from kafka
    val source = KafkaSource.builder[String].setBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
      .setTopics("movie_rating_records").setGroupId("my-group").setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest)
      .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new SimpleStringSchema())
      .setBounded(OffsetsInitializer.latest).build()


    //    val inputDataStream = env.readTextFile("a.txt")
    val inputDataStream = env.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "Kafka Source")
    val dataStream = inputDataStream
      .map( data =>{
        val arr = data.split(",")
        ( arr(0),arr(1).toInt,arr(2).toInt,arr(3).toFloat,arr(4).toLong)
      })
    val (counterUserIdPos,counterUserIdNeg,counterMovieIdPos,counterMovieIdNeg,counterUserId2MovieId) = commonProcess(dataStream)
    counterUserIdPos.map(x =>{
      val jedisIns = new Jedis(host,port,100000)
      jedisIns.set("batch2feature_userId_rating1_"+x._1.toString, x._2.toString)
      jedisIns.close()
    })
    env.execute("test")
  }
}
```

The input stream from Kafka is a string split by a comma, for example: `1542295208rating,556,112852,1.0,1542295208`. The above code process the string and puts them into another datastream process function. And finally, it writes the result into Redis.

Any help or hints on resolving the issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here aer a few pointers I can think of

Netty is the internal serialization mechanism of Flink => from the stack trace we know the error is likely occurring in one of the `.map` or so, not when interacting with Kafka nor Redis.

Serialization issues are sometimes happening in Flink when using Scala. Maybe the second `.map` is somehow causing connection pools or some other context instance to be serialized into the lambda, so replacing it with a Flink `SinkFunction` might help (in addition to improving performance since you'd only create one `Jedis` instance per partition).

Investigate also what serialization is going on in the `commonProcess`.

Essentially, you should be hunting for a place where the code somehow needs to serialize some instance whose type would confuse the Flink serialization mechanism.